# Which country has the most cabinet ministers with PhDs?

Tags: government, education, cabinet

I would be happy to know which country has the maximum number of ministers with PhD degrees.

I ask this question because I was reading about the new ministers appointed by the Modi government. Looks like the cabinet has at least 5 PhDs.

I hope I can find answers of nations with 8-9 or more cabinet ministers with PhDs.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Assuming we're allowing past governments - at the beginning of 2011, the second Merkel Cabinet (Germany) included twelve ministers with PhDs or other doctoral degrees.

Unfortunately, only ten still retain their degrees, as in February 2011, Karl-Theodor zu Guttenberg's doctorate was withdrawn by the University of Bayreuth after plagiarism was discovered (see [Guttenberg plagiarism scandal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guttenberg_plagiarism_scandal)). A couple of years later, the University of Düsseldorf [revoked Annette Schavan's doctorate](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-europe-21395102) for the same reason.

Nevertheless, at the beginning of 2011, twelve out of sixteen ministers held doctorates.

| Name | Position | Subject |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Angela Merkel | Chancellor | Quantum Chemistry |
| Guido Westerwelle | Federal Minister for Foreign Affairs | Law |
| Rainer Brüderle | Federal Minister of Economics and Technology | Economics |
| Thomas de Maizière | Federal Minister of the Interior | Law |
| Wolfgang Schäuble | Federal Minister of Finance | Law |
| Ursula von der Leyen | Federal Minister of Labour and Social Affairs | Medicine |
| Karl-Theodor zu Guttenberg | Federal Minister of Defence | Law (revoked in 2011) |
| Kristina Schröder | Federal Minister for Family Affairs, Senior Citizens, Women and Youth | Political Science |
| Philipp Rösler | Federal Minister of Health | Cardiothoracic Surgery |
| Peter Ramsauer | Federal Minister of Transport, Building and Urban Affairs | Business Economics |
| Norbert Röttgen | Federal Minister for the Environment, Nature Conservation, and Nuclear Safety | Law |
| Annette Schavan | Federal Minister of Education and Research | Philosophy (revoked in 2013) |

Comment: Man, two doctorates revoked in a cabinet in a few years is quite the trivia point anyway

Comment: @AzorAhai-him-, after some initial cases there has been a systematic look at the academic credentials of political figures, who often found the time to earn their degree in parallel to a starting political career when a PhD is usually a full-time task. The "plagiarism hunters" might have been driven by political motives to uncover non-political misconduct. There have been several more cases, since, plus some possibly getting ahead of themselves (complaining that a non-academic political manifesto does not follow scientific citation standards ...).

Comment: @o.m. it doesnt matter what they're driven by, the fact that plagiarisms, fake CVs etc. are so rampant in German politics is a shame. It's like blaming Snowden for uncovering the massive NSA spying.

Comment: @Hobbamok Sadly I don't think plagiarism is "rampant in Germany" more than in other countries. Probably in Germany when they find out they take drastic measures against it. I bet many PhDs turned politicians (especially in Law and other non-scientific fields) did not earn their title honestly in many countries. The problem is that even if the press finds out, the "scandals" are soon swept under the carpet. ...

Comment: @Hobbamok ... In Italy we have our shares of fake degrees (not only PhDs, but Masters as well) in public figures, but people easily forget and even if they are momentarily shadowed by the scandal, they get reelected soon most of the time, if their ties with their parties is strong. Not to mention "independent media" which are not truly independent because they have vested interests in supporting the aforementioned politicians.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati--Codidact.com same here, in like 2010 Gutenberg was basically ousted from politics but now everyone is so numb to it, nobody cares anymore. Neither the politicians nor the voters

Comment: @Hobbamok That Gutenberg case made quite the news here in Italy at the time. The fact that, when discovered, he apologized publicly instead of trying to find excuses was rather unheard of here. Usually when such a thing happens in Italy, the "perp" adopts one or more of these strategy: (1) to cry out loud for unjust break of their privacy;  (2) to threaten the media, or the specific journalist, to sue them for defamation (even if there's no legal basis - the audience is unaware); (3) to find some weird explanation with a few logic leaps (the audience can't thing logically); ...

Comment: @Hobbamok ... (4)  to give some utterly unbelievable explanation. [Here an example of ex Italian Minister Scajola (2nd paragraph)](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claudio_Scajola#Caso_Anemone:_prescritto_dopo_assoluzione_(2010-2014)). He stated that "... a quota of my house has been paid for unbeknownst to me...", regarding some suspect payments for his house.

Comment: @Hobbamok, I'm not trying to endorse academic dishonesty and I surely hope I haven't given the impression. But *right now*, the chance to be caught is higher for a political figure in Germany, because people are systematically looking. That distorts statistics.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati--Codidact.com In many countries (I am thinking about France or the UK for example), PhD holders are rare in government and not particularly respected. The opposite is true in Germany and that's a structural reason why plagiarism would be rampant there. Don't know about Italy, maybe the situation is similar there. (+1)

Comment: @LorenzoDonati--Codidact.com yeah back then, nowadays they don't care if its found out. Some step down, a lot don't. In a way Gutenberg was by far the most honest back then lol.

Comment: @o.m. yeah, absolutely but my main point is how the ones found guilty don't get excommunicated from their party/politics anymore, its just taken as another 2 week scandal that'll be forgotten by the end of the month

Answer (score 33):

The Federal government of Ethiopia has 12 PhDs. The names are listed below:

1. Abiy Ahmed (PhD)     Prime Minister
2. Kene’a Yadeta (PhD)  Minister of Defense
3. Getahun Mekuria (PhD)    Minister of Education
4. Lia Tadesse (PhD)    Minister of Health
5. Samuel Urkato (PhD)  Minister of Science and Higher Education
6. Sileshi Bekele (PhD)     Minister of Water, Irrigation and Energy
7. Hirut Kassaw (PhD)   Minister of Culture and Tourism
8. Ergoge Tesfaye (PhD)     Minister of Labour and Social Affairs
9. Abraham Belay (PhD)  Minister of Innovation and Technology
10. Fitsum Assefa (PhD)     Minister of Planning and Development Commission
11. Gedion Timothewos (PhD)     Attorney General with the Rank of Minister
12. Hirut Woldemariam (PhD)     Social Sector Advisor to the Prime Minister with the Rank of Minister

Reference: [Website of the Ethiopian Embassy in London](https://www.ethioembassy.org.uk/political-affairs/government-of-ethiopia/)

Comment: Is this more than other countries?

Comment: hmm, that link does not work for me.

Comment: @CGCampbell See it [here](https://imgur.com/a/9gBrQn6)

Comment: Where did they get their PhDs? Which subjects?

Answer (score 19):

The [Iranian government](https://www.president.ir/en/president/cabinet) has many PhDs as well. (At least 20!)

1. [President Dr. Rouhani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hassan_Rouhani) obtained a PhD degree in Constitutional Law in 1999 for a thesis titled The Flexibility of Shariah (Islamic Law) with reference to the Iranian experience.
2. First Vice President [Eshaq Jahangiri Kouhshahi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eshaq_Jahangiri) received a PhD from Islamic Azad University, Science and Research Branch, Tehran in industrial management.
3. Head of Presidential Office and Chief of Staff [Mahmoud Vaezi Joz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahmoud_Vaezi) holds Ph.D in International Relations from Warsaw University.
4. Vice-President for Economic Affairs [Mohammad Nahavandian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohammad_Nahavandian) received his Ph.D in economics in 1989 .
5. Vice-President and Head of Plan and Budget Organisation [Mohammad Bagher Nobakht](https://www.president.ir/EN/100273) 
   <sub>*Possibly*</sub>
6. Vice-President for Legal Affairs Laaya Joneidi 
   <sub>*possibly* [Ref 1](https://web.archive.org/web/20170809211641/http://ilsp.law.harvard.edu/fellows-archive/) [Ref 2](https://www.president.ir/en/100118)</sub>
7. Vice-President for Parliamentary Affairs Hossein-Ali Amiri
   <sub>*possibly* [Reference](https://www.president.ir/en/102192)</sub>
8. Vice-President for science and technology affairs [Sorena Sattari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorena_Sattari) received a Doctor of Philosophy in Mechanical Engineering from Sharif University of Technology, Iran.
9. Vice-President for Women and Family Affairs [Ma'soumeh Ebtekar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masoumeh_Ebtekar) holds a PhD in immunology from Tarbiat Modares University in 1995.
10. Vice- President and Head of Atomic Energy Organisation [Ali Akbar Salehi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ali_Akbar_Salehi) received a PhD in nuclear engineering from the Massachusetts Institute of Technology in 1977.
11. Vice-President and Head of Department of Environment [Issa Kalantari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isa_Kalantari) obtained PhD in agricultural physiology from Iowa State University.
12. Minister of Education [Mohsen Haji Mirzaei](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohsen_Haji-Mirzaei) earned a Doctorate in Sociology from the Islamic Azad University, Tehran.
13. Minister of Intelligence [Mahmoud Alavi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahmoud_Alavi) holds a PhD in Islamic jurisprudence and law from Ferdowsi University in Mashad.
14. Minister of Economic Affairs and Finance Farhad Dejpasand
    *possibly* [Reference](https://www.president.ir/EN/106695)
15. Minister of Foreign Affairs [Mohammad Javad Zarif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohammad_Javad_Zarif) obtained a Ph.D. in international law and policy in 1988.
16. Minister of Health and Medical Education Saeid Namaki 
    *possibly* [Reference](https://www.president.ir/EN/107910)
17. Minister of Agriculture Jihad Kazem Khavazi 
    *possibly* [Reference](https://www.president.ir/en/114647)
18. Minister of Interior [Abdolreza Rahmani Fazli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abdolreza_Rahmani_Fazli) received a PhD in geography from Tarbiat Modarres University.
19. Minister of Science, Research and Technology [Mansour Gholami](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mansour_Gholami)
     [Reference](https://www.president.ir/EN/101340)
20. Minister of Energy [Reza Ardakanian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reza_Ardakanian) holds a PhD in Water Resources Management from McMaster University in Hamilton, Canada.

Comment: Not sure why you're including so many unconfirmed. Even without them, the list is still impressive.

Comment: I think the "unconfirmed" people are really PhDs. If you search `site:president.ir president appoints`, you can see search results with names of people with or without **Dr** prefix. I have written the word *possibly* because Wikipedia doesn't mention it. And it would be a humongous task to confirm all those through other sources.

Comment: ah, ok. I can't search that site where I am now, but will do so when home. Thanks

Comment: "agricultural physiology" aka "crop physiology".

Comment: The scandals surrounding some of these PhDs are quite disastrous under _normal_ circumstances. Fun fact: some Iranians (ahem...) are even ashamed to mention their hardly earned PhDs because these people have ruined the word and made it devoid of its meaning. Sadly, it's a shame that the situation is so _effed_-up that nobody cares anymore about minor! issues. R.I.P. academic honesty.